# Rails 3 Error when using OR with a where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having a strange issue when using the Where clause in Rails. I imagine it has something to do with my OR operator syntax.  Here is my query:

```
  Cookie.where("ID = ? OR ID = ? OR ID = ? OR ID = ?", chocolate.to_s, sugar.to_s, peanut_butter.to_s, oatmeal.to_s)
```

When I attempt to execute the query my application just hangs endlessly. However, If I submit a query that looks like this:

```
  Cookie.where("ID = ?", chocolate.to_s)
```

I get the expected result. Any help with the proper format to this where clause would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

**UPDATE**
I went into the rails console and did as you suggested. This was the result:

```
  SELECT \"TBLCookies\".* FROM \"TBLCookies\"  WHERE (ID in ('4','3','2','1'))
```

This seems correct.  I opened up SQL Developer, pasted this query in, and ran it.  I got the expected result. So everything seems to be fine there.  However, when I try to run the query in the rails console I get nothing back.  The console just hangs indefinitely.  Any insight into what could be going wrong would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do this

```
Cookie.where("ID in (?)",[chocolate, sugar, peanut_butter, oatmeal].collect(&:to_s))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Viren, but the syntax that you gave me also makes my app hang indefinitely. I wonder if it matters that I am using an Oracle DB?

Comment: @CookieEmpire Just test the command on Oracle do .to_sql on the above command and run it on Oracle Console see if it return any error or so never worked with Oracle as such but I think it should work fine since Mysql and Oracle use the same syntax if feel

Comment: I updated my initial post with the output from the rails console.  The SQL syntax is correct. There has got to be some other weird issue going on here. . .

Comment: @CookieEmpire I ask you run that command in `ORACLE CONSOLE` does the command run over there I not which version of Rails are you using If latest try add explain to what the problem

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have access to the Oracle Console.